# How to integrate payment gateway in sharetribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sharetribe

I am new in sharetribe, and I integrated sharetribe in my application, now I want to integrate payment option in my ruby application. I search about that but in my admin side there is no option for payment.

How to enable payment option in sharetribe?

Answer (score 1):

The Sharetribe open source code currently includes code for BrainTree payment integration, but that code is no longer used by the hosted solution and not updated by the core team and might be removed in the future.

The open source code includes also code related to PayPal payments, but that code relies to special arrangements with Sharetribe core team and PayPal (to facilitate marketplace admin onboarding) and thus its not directly usable with open source installations.

So there payment options that the Sharetribe open source code can offer out of the box are not very good at the moment. We hope to improve the situation in the future.

Bit more info can be found at: http://support.sharetribe.com/knowledgebase/articles/577014 (in part "Payments")

Answer (score 1):

Sharetribe has the stripe and PayPal integration.

But you have to enable from admin then you have to add some insertions on DB.

**# set PayPal gateway

```
    INSERT INTO payment_settings SET active = 1, community_id = 1, payment_gateway = 'paypal', payment_process = 'preauthorize', commission_from_seller = 0, minimum_price_cents = 400, minimum_transaction_fee_cents = 0, confirmation_after_days = 14, created_at = NOW(), updated_at = NOW();
```

## define variables

```
 SET @username=(SELECT username FROM people LIMIT 1);

 SET @owner_email=(SELECT e.address from people p left join emails e on 

 (e.person_id=p.id) where p.username=@username);

 SET @merchant_account_id="[merchant_account_id]";

 SET @paypal_username="[paypal_username]";

 SET @paypal_app_id="APP-80W284485P519543T";


 UPDATE people set is_admin=1 where username=@username;

 INSERT INTO paypal_accounts (person_id, community_id, email, payer_id, 
 created_at, updated_at, active) VALUES (null, 1, @owner_email, 
 @merchant_account_id, NOW(), NOW(), 1);

 SET @paypal_account_id=(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

 INSERT INTO billing_agreements (paypal_account_id, billing_agreement_id, created_at, updated_at, paypal_username_to, request_token) VALUES (@paypal_account_id, 'fake-agreement', NOW(), NOW(), @paypal_username, @paypal_app_id);

 INSERT INTO order_permissions (paypal_account_id, created_at, updated_at, request_token, paypal_username_to, scope, verification_code, onboarding_id, permissions_granted) VALUES (@paypal_account_id, NOW(), NOW(), 'fake-token', @paypal_username, null, null, null, 1);

  INSERT INTO transaction_processes (community_id, process, author_is_seller, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (1, 'preauthorize', 1, NOW(), NOW());
```

SET @transaction_process_id=(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());

```
  UPDATE listing_shapes SET transaction_process_id=@transaction_process_id where name='selling';

  #if you have listings added before you should modify transaction_process_id in listing entries too**


http://publish.yexperiment.com/post/156715320289/sharetribe-with-paypal-payments-the-lost
```

This will help you a lot.
Cheers